# Apache Virtual Host and Sonicwall

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, windows-server-2012, sonicwall

**General**

I am attempting to setup IP or name based virtual hosts in Apache behind a SonicWall firewall. In house, both virtual host methods work flawlessly (even on different subnets that cross the firewall). The issues start when a client requests a virtual host from a remote location. To clarify, the first virtual host specified is served when called by IP (or name), but the second gives an unresponsive error.

Note: The Public Server Wizard in SonicWall was used to create the firewall rules for both virtual hosts and both are identical with the exception of private IP and external IP.

**Specifics**

- SonicWall Model: NSA 2400 MX
- SonicWall Firmware: SonicOS Enhanced 5.7.2.0-10o
- Apache Version: 2.4.3
- Server: Windows Server 2012

**Virtual Host Config**

```
<VirtualHost x.x.x.4:443>
DocumentRoot "d:/A/Path"
ServerName a.domain.com
ServerAlias a.domain.com
# Snipped 
</VirtualHost>    


<VirtualHost x.x.x.5:443>
DocumentRoot "d:/Another/Path"
ServerName b.domain.com
ServerAlias b.domain.com
# Snipped
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to access the website from inside but not from outside, your SonicWall Appliance is definitively blocking the traffic. Could you give us the firewall rules and the nat policies defined on your SonicWall appliance?

Regards,